# Get and pass Json file with PHP

Tags: php, ajax, json

I have a Json file in the server:

*file.json* :

```
{"max":"512", "min":"1", ...
```

I get it with an ajax call:

```
$.ajax({                                      
    url: 'load_json.php',
    type: "POST",
    data: { id: id },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(resp) {
        console.log(resp.json.max);
    }
});
```

Where *load_json.php* is:

```
    $json = file_get_contents("file.json");
    $response = array('json' => $json);
    echo json_encode($response);
```

But in the console I get *undefined*. Why?

A possible **solution** is:

```
$response = array('json' => json_decode($json));
```

Is this the most effective solution?

Comment: var json_string = JSON.stringify(resp); `try console.dir(json_string)`

Comment: @TismonVarghese  file.json is too big. The computer freezes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your php you are reading file.json as a string and then this string is putting to the array, so javascript cant parse it as a proper json object. Use json_decode function in your php code:

```
$json = file_get_contents("file.json");
$response = array('json' => json_decode($json)); //here
echo json_encode($response);
```

or:

```
$json = file_get_contents("file.json");
$response = '{"json":' . $json . '}'; //here
echo $response;
```

but use first solution.